# the eigenvalues of matrix $X$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please hint me. I want to calculate the eigenvalues of matrix $ X$, which $ a,b,c,d,e$ are natural numbers.
$$\mathbf{X}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c&d&e\\
a+1&b-1&c&0&e\\
a+1&b&c-1&0&0\\
a+1&0&0&d-1&e\\
a+1&b&0&d&e-1
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Is there any one to help me?

Comment: I did give you an answer, if you believe something is missing from it, you can always comment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,c,d,e$ are unknown quantities (even if you know they are natural numbers), it is impossible to calculate the eigenvalues of $X$. They will most certainly not all be equal to $0$ (because the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of the matrix)

I think you made 2 errors in your problem

1. You are trying to solve a problem which is too general. Even trying to find eigenvalues of a $5\times 5$ matrix with no unknown quantities is usually impossible to do exactly and by hand. Introducing even more unknowns means that your function $\det(xI - X)$ will be a function of $6$ variables, and finding zeroes of such functions, especially by hand, is next to impossible.
2. You calculated the determinant of $(xI-X)$ incorrectly, since $X$ obviously has eigenvalues which are not equal to $0$.

Comment: The matrix $\displaystyle \left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$ is not a zero matrix, yet its eigenvalues are all $0$. You should delete the sentence "the only matrix with all zero eigenvalues is the zero matrix". Your other comments are great.

Comment: In fact, a matrix has *only* zero as an eigenvalue iff it is a nilpotent matrix. There certainly are non-zero nilpotent matrices whenever $\;n\ge 2\;$ .

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks for the comments, I updated my answers